# First derivative of $e^{-2x}/(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could someone please help me with these derivatives?

I have to find the first derivative of

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-2x}}{1-x}.$$

Then I have to find the second derivative of that.

For the first derivative I get

$$ f'(x) = \frac{-2e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^2} $$

The answer book disagrees with me though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$, where $u=e^{-2x} \Rightarrow u'=-2e^{-2x} $ and $v=1-x \Rightarrow v'=-1$.

Now, as $\displaystyle\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}$, then
$$f'(x) =\frac{(1-x)(-2e^{-2x})-e^{-2x}(-1)}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{-2e^{-2x}+2xe^{-2x}+e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{(2x-1)e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, that rule is what I needed. Now I still have to find the second derivative. Do I use a combination of the chain rule and the rule that you listed above?

Comment: Yes, for the second derivative, $$u=(2x-1)e^{-2x} \Rightarrow u'=(2x-1)(e^{-2x})'+(2x-1)'(e^{-2x})=-2(2x-1)e^{-2x}+2e^{-2x}=-4xe^{-2x}-4e^{-2x}$$ and $$v=(1-x)^2 \Rightaarrow v'=2(1-x)=2-2x$$

Comment: Yes, for the second derivative, $$u=(2x-1)e^{-2x} \Rightarrow u'=(2x-1)(e^{-2x})'+(2x-1)'(e^{-2x})=-2(2x-1)e^{-2x}+2e^{-2x}=-4xe^{-2x}-4e^{-2x}$$ and $$v=(1-x)^2 \Rightarrow v'=2(1-x)=2-2x$$. Finaly, use  $(uv)′=\frac{vu′−uv′}{v^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\left(\dfrac{h}{g}\right)'=\dfrac{h'g-hg'}{g^2}$

You have $h(x)=e^{-2x},\,h'(x)=-2e^{-2x},\,g(x)=1-x,\,g'(x)=-1$.